# How do i setup Login module in my web application? in Java?

Tags: java

I am making web application in java. My username and passwords as well as roles are stored in database. I could use jdbcRealm, but it forces me to use a specific structure which i dont have in my project. So, how do i do it? I am using Glassfish v3.0 with Netbeans 6.8. I read few tutorials about custom LoginModule but i am not getting anything out of it. How do you all people do it practically in your projects? If you can show me code of custom LoginModule then also it will do.

Waiting for replies.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually i am using JSF 2.0. Does this Spring security work well with JSF?

Comment: Yes it does.  Have a look here.  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2008/jw-04-acegi-jsf.html

Comment: Thanks Chandru but i am actually doing login through web service. How will it work in that case? The link that you pointed to doesn't show it.
Actually my JSF page will contact webservice and web service will contact EJBs. If you can give me any link for doing it, it would be great!